# Is it possible to make a transaction which will still allow ReadOnly requests?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, transactions, transactionscope

I have a batch process at the moment and it can take up to an hour to run. It's not database intensive, it's just that there's a lot of things like web calls it's got to do.

I have a transaction wrapped around the whole thing so if anything goes wrong, I will roll back.

Is it possible to make this transaction so it only blocks requests which write to the database and not Read Only? If not, why not? Is this just a natural limitation of the database?

I'm in .net 4.0 and I'm using a `TransactionScope` for this task.

Comment: An hour long transaction? Did I understand that correct?

Comment: yeah... db can't be accessed during. Is this just a really bad idea?

Comment: This is a terrible idea. Load into a staging table, and then bulk transfer it over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do this. Load into a staging table. When the operation completes, bulk transfer it over to the actual table.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, something like this is not going to succeed at all; most resource managers by default won't let a transaction go on for that long, and if they did (and if multiple resource managers are involved) then depending on the amount of data that is being updated/modified, the act of committing a transaction could take a *very* long time.

If you are just looking to block out database access during your process, you are better off setting a flag in the database and then having other functions in your application fail if the flag is set.

The scope of your application can affect where the flag is stored; if you only have one instance running, you can store the flag in memory, but if there are multiple instances, you probably have to check the database every time.